# Get content of the page given by an URL thru Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, proxy, hyperlink

Does anybody here solved a similar problem?

I have a link that contains nothing but another link.

For example, given a URL lets say it is www.abc123proxy.info. And then that URL contains another URL on its page (yeah, just text) lets say the URL for this one is www.masked-url.com?token=231940812093810. I need go to the second URL but I only have the first URL.

This is what I want to happen:

```
$(document).ready(function() {window.location = 'www.abc123proxy.info';});
// But I wanted to go to the link inside the page of that URL.
```

Is this problem can be solve using javascript? I'm open for other better solution if you have.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't understand that a bit

Comment: Basically, I want to get the HTML Source of the first url in javascript code. The first url contains the second url in text (means there are totally no html tags on it).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        url:'first_url',
        type:'get',
        success:function(data){
          var _newUrl=$(data).find('a:first');
        }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, there is no <a> tag on the first_url. Its just a text of link. No html tag nor head nor body, just text. How can I get it?

Comment: sucess:function(data){ now here data is ur required link}

Comment: I tried alert(data); inside success and it returns a blank space.

Comment: $.get('first_url', function(data) {window.location.href=data});

Comment: I tried to use the code above. But it continuously reloads the page because the 'data' is a blank space.

Comment: $.ajax({url: 'first_url',type: 'get',dataType: 'text',success: function(data){var newUrl=data;window.location.href=newUrl;}});

Comment: 1>make sure u r sever allows get request,2>the url ur are passing to make ajax request, just try that url in browser and see what result it is returning.