# Call API URL from browser rather than include it in jsp page and call from server

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

In my JSP page i am importing some api url that give some images.

my server blocks api url but my browser show those images that coming from api url.

My question is there any way to call the url from browser itself instead of calling from server side?

Answer (score 0):

If the API you're using only returns images, you can simply use `<img src="http://your.api.url/" />`.

Otherwise, you can call the URL using JavaScript, as put forward [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075498/1225328).